# Animating the cell entrance/exiting of a scrolling list

Tags: swiftui

I want to animate a cell as it appears when the user scrolls a list.

I have this code

```
struct ContentView: View {
  let st = stride(from: 0, to: 500, by: 2)
  @State private var numbers = Array(stride(from: 0, to: 500, by: 2))

  var body: some View {
      ScrollView {
        LazyVStack {
          ForEach(self.numbers, id: \.self) {number in
            RV(number: number)
          }
        }
      }
  }
}

struct RV: View {
  
  @State private var rotation:Double = -30
  var number:Int
  
  var body: some View {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
      .fill(Color.red)
      .frame(width: 300, height: 150)
      .overlay(Text("\(number)").foregroundColor(.white).font(.largeTitle))
      .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(rotation), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
      .animation(Animation.smooth(duration: 1.0), value: rotation)
      .onAppear{
        withAnimation {
          rotation = 0
        }
      }
  }
}
```

The idea was to have the cell entering the view and animate like it happens in the carousel mode for the watch.

In my code the cell starts off screen, below the fold, rotated by -30 degrees in Y.

The idea was to animate the rotation to zero, as the cell approaches the position where it is centralized vertically in the screen. But I could not figure out how to do that.

While I was trying to do that, I decided to create this code to test how could this animation be done.

If you run the code, you will see that you can barely see the cell animating. You have to scroll fast to see some animation. Even using a lazy stack, the animations don't show how I was expecting them.

How to animate like this:

1. the cell is offscreen, below the fold, and it is -20 degrees in Y
2. as the cell scrolls up and approaches the vertical middle of the screen, rotation in Y approaches 0.
3. If the user continues to scroll up, rotation continues to increase, this time to positive values, until it reaches 20.
4. if the user decides to scroll down, rotations decrease.

In resume:

- cell is off screen below the fold (Y = -20)
- cell is at the vertical middle (Y = 0)
- cell is off screen above the fold (Y = +20)

Comment: Just to be clear, when the scroll view is stationary, do you still want to see the cells at the top and bottom rotated? Or do you want no rotations at all when the scroll view stops scrolling?

Comment: yes, like the carousel on the watch. The cell enters the scene rotated, starts to lose the rotation as the approach the vertical middle and starts rotating again as the live the midle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I thought of is to use the `viewAligned` scroll target behaviour so that you can get the current scroll position, then send that scroll position to each subview. The subviews can then compare the scroll position with their own position in the scroll view (in this case, `number`) to decide how much they want to rotate.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var position: Int = 50
    
    var body: some View{
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(0..<100) { i in
                    RV(number: i, scrollPosition: $position).id(i)
                }
            }
            .scrollTargetLayout()
        }
        .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
        .scrollPosition(id: Binding($position), anchor: .center)
    }
}

struct RV: View {
    
    let number: Int
    
    @Binding var scrollPosition: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 150)
                // I don't have a watch so I don't know how the watch carousel is supposed to look
                // here is something that I think looks good
                .rotation3DEffect(
                    // you can change this to any function of (scrollPosition - number)
                    // as you see fit 
                    .degrees(Double((scrollPosition - number) * 16)),
                    axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0),
                    anchor: scrollPosition - number > 0 ? .leading : .trailing
                )
            Text("\(number)")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .rotation3DEffect(
                    .degrees(Double((scrollPosition - number) * 16)),
                    axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0),
                    anchor: scrollPosition - number > 0 ? .leading : .trailing
                )
        }
        .animation(Animation.smooth(duration: 1.0), value: scrollPosition)
    }
}
```

Of course, the rotations are not exactly "real time". The views only change rotations whenever the scroll target changes, but I think that is a good enough approximation, particularly if the scroll targets are small.

Comment: that's brilliant! Thanks!!!!!!